# what does those lines of code mean in makefile ? can you explaain to me this exemple?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am  having this exemple below of makefile and I can't understand what this means ,; 
specially the targets what does .C.O means ?

```
  .c.o :
       gcc –c $*.c
    .c.o :
       gcc –c $<
```

thanks in advance

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Suffix-Rules

Comment: It means `%.o : %.c`